# Eclipse compiles cocos2d-x core files on every run

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2d-x v2.2.1 with Android NDK v r9 on Windows

This is the CDT Build Console output:

```
10:36:27 **** Build of configuration Default for project AsteroidsClone ****
ndk-build.cmd 
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module cocos2dcpp_shared    
Android NDK:   LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=    
Android NDK: WARNING:C:\AndroidDev\cocos2d-x-2.2.1/cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= main.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= Asteroid.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= Bullet.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= GameLoop.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos2dcpp_shared <= Ship.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= AssetsManager.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCBFileLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCBReader.cpp
C:\AndroidDev\cocos2d-x-2.2.1/extensions/CCBReader/CCBReader.cpp:383:52: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCControlButtonLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCControlLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCLabelBMFontLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCLabelTTFLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCLayerColorLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCLayerGradientLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCLayerLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCMenuItemImageLoader.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : cocos_extension_static <= CCMenuItemLoader.cpp
```

And more like it, for Chipmunk, Box2D, etc.
Takes 3-6 minutes on average every time.

I checked this out:
[Cocos2d-x sources always compiling](http://cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/19485?r=19513#message-19513)

And then I checked this file:
`C:\AndroidDev\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r9\build\core\definitions.mk`

At line no 113, I found:
`$1:| $$(__ndk_file_dir)`

And one guy's answer about the patch, according to the link above, this line I just mentioned above is correct. If I remove the space after the `|` symbol, my build doesn't happen.

What else could be the problem that my cocos2d-x sources are getting compiled again and again?!

Comment: Are you generating or making changes to `Application.mk` or `Android.mk` file every-time with build?

Comment: If you mean manually, no. 

I think you might want to know this:
(in my project's jni/Android.mk file)

`CLASSES_FILES   := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/*.cpp)
CLASSES_FILES   := $(CLASSES_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
`  

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CLASSES_FILES)`

Comment: Does the rebuild happen only in Eclipse, or it is reproduced when you run `ndk-build.cmd` from Windows command-line? BTW, there is a warning, which could cause the problem. To fix the warning, I'd suggest to run `ndk-build DUMP_LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and analyze the console output.

Comment: Probably you are reproducing `Android.mk` file on build, otherwise only recently changed files get compiled.